# How to conditionally convert inches to cm in MySQL (or similar conversions during SELECT)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
value    unit
-----    -----
100      cm
30       in
120      cm
35       in
37       in
29       in
```

In my selection, I'd like to convert inches to centimeters.  Something like the following:

```
SELECT AVG(unit = in ? value*2.54 : value) FROM data_table;
```

What is the proper syntax, or method to perform this type of selection in MySQL?

Comment: You could also convert them during storage, since that would be done only once, but selecting is done many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(value) FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE unit
      WHEN "cm" THEN value
      WHEN "in" THEN value*2.54
      END AS value
    FROM data_table
) AS all_in_cm
```

Answer (score 2):

You could 'rollup' [@Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863454/how-to-conditionally-convert-inches-to-cm-in-mysql-or-similar-conversions-durin/7863479#7863479)'s solution into a single SELECT without subqueries:

```
SELECT AVG(value * CASE unit WHEN 'cm' THEN 1 WHEN 'in' THEN 2.54 END)
FROM data_table
```

Alternatively you could use an tiny lookup subselect for the units, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(d.value * u.factor)
FROM data_table d
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 'cm' AS unit, 1 AS factor UNION ALL SELECT 'in', 2.54) u
    ON d.unit = u.unit
```

Comment: +1 clever lookup, could throw it in a separate *actual* table :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE d.Unit
        WHEN 'in' THEN d.Value * 2.54
        ELSE d.Value
       END AS centemeters
FROM data_table at d;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONV_IN_CM (measurement INT,  base_type ENUM('in','cm'))
RETURNS FLOAT(65,4) 
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN IF(base_type = 'in', measurement * 2.54, 
       IF(base_type = 'cm', measurement / 2.54, NULL));
```

Below is the syntax for this command. Text within square brackets (i.e, [ and ] ) are optional. Choices are separated by bars (i.e, | ). Ellipses preceded by a comma indicates a repeating pattern. Ellipses before or after syntax are used to highlight a relevant except from the larger syntax. Text displayed in italic letters represent text that should be replaced with the specific names related to the database (e.g., column with the name of the column).

```
CONV_IN_CM(measurement, {in | cm})
```