# How to sort sizes like 5/16, 1-1/4, 1-1/2

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, sorting

I'm trying to think of a way to sort a list of sizes, for example 5/16, 1/4, 7/8, 1, 1-1/8, 1-1/2, 10mm, 12mm, etc.

The list is a varchar column in sql server 2008.

I'm thinking regular expressions might be a viable option, just wondering if a good way to do this already exists.

Thanks

Comment: you example not clear , can be 5/16 , 1-1/8 or 10mm ? 3 different type

Comment: and the 1-1/8 ,is dath meen between 1 and 1/8 ?*

Comment: 1-1/8 means one and one eight. and yes unfortunately they do mix between imperial and metric.

Comment: @Mark, see my answer, your most reliable solution is to store what is typed, and also convert it all to mm (or some standard decimal based unit of measure), and store that in a second column for sorting.  It's really not that hard to do that math in code prior to saving what the user entered.  A regex won't really help you any, as it can't perform the math that is needed to properly normalize the values prior to sorting.

Answer (score 2):

You could have another column with the numeric measure in the same units, and then sort it. But if you sort it as varchar, you'd be sorting it alphanumerically.

Answer (score 2):

Is 5/16 in inches?  It doesn't say.

I would store another column with normalized data.  Convert all values to mm and store it as well. So your db has a "display column" which is 13mm or 1/2", but both records have an "in mm" column with a value of 13 (or 1/2" would have a value of 12.7 if you aren't rounding).

Then when you sort, you are sorting everything by the same unit of measure.  It will be faster (since you're sorting numbers) and you don't need to do conversions on the fly.

Or store units and value seperately, like this question, and sort on the result of the case statement.  but I wouldn't recommend this, it's over complex, and slower.

[How to conditionally convert inches to cm in MySQL (or similar conversions during SELECT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863454/how-to-conditionally-convert-inches-to-cm-in-mysql-or-similar-conversions-durin)